# Phantomjs change port page.open()

Tags: javascript, phantomjs, tcp

I'm trying to do web scraping with PhantomJS and to open multiple instances occurred to me to open multiple servers and from there scraping web pages.
With this idea I'm getting together a pool of instances (without using external libraries).

My question is,

***page.open () will open the url from the port 8888 I specified or will use the port defalut for web connections (80, 8080, 443, etc)?***

If you use the port I specified (in this case 8888) would be very good as it could make faster and more efficient web scrapings that if using a single port.

Thanks for your attention!

PD: I give you a simple example of the code I'm trying to use. Works but do not know how that works page.open () with ports.

```js
var webPage = require('webpage');
var server = require('webserver').create();

function onRequest (request, response) {
 var page = webPage.create();
 page.open('http://www.google.com/', function(status) {
   console.log('Status: ' + status);
   console.log(page.content);
 });
}

var service = server.listen(8888, onRequest);

if (service) {
 console.log('Server OK');
} else {
 console.log('Server close');
 phantom.exit();
}
```

Comment: Default 80 port.....http://phantomjs.org/api/webpage/method/open.html

Comment: uhh .. and is there any way to change it? Thanks!

Comment: Nope...if you are looking for ways to optimize your web scraper, then you need another approach!

Comment: Ok, thanks Hackerman. How do you see the idea of opening multiple servers and each is assigned a group of urls to scrape?

Comment: You want to scrape all the html of certain parts?...so my answer should be, it depends on the problem that you want to resolve

Comment: I need to scrape many websites running ajax requests, for this reason can not close the page and need it is open to continue receiving information from the server of the website.
If I create a single instance of PhantomJS, open many pages it becomes very slow. 
so I got the idea to open pages on different ports ...

Comment: Open many pages is like opening new tabs.

Comment: ahh I did not know it worked well. Hackerman thank you very much, now I understand a little running PhantomJS!!!

Comment: You just need to remember that phantomjs is a headless browser, like chrome but with no visible interface.